# Debian 9 install on an old PC shows Kernel Panic and does not boot

Tags: debian, kernel, debian-installer, kernel-panic

I found an old PC with a AMD Athlon XP and 256 MB of RAM, so i tried to install Debian 9 and use it as a test server.

The install was completed without problems, but when i tried to boot the system from for the first time the problems started to show up. I managed to fix certain problems with searches on StackExchange or by playing with the BIOS:

- System trying to load a Floppy drive even if is not installed (disabled Floppy support in the Bios)
- "ACPI Error: Method Execution failed" (disabled ACPI on the Bios)
- "ALERT! UUID=... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!" (replaced "root=UUID=..." by "root=/" on the GRUB launch parameters)

After fixing all of those, there's still one that I'm unable to fix:

> Call trace:
>
> [< ca2f6c82 >] ? dump_stack+0x55/0x73
>
> [< ca16879a >] ? panic0x94/0x1d8
>
> [< ca06c15e >] ? do_exit+0x9fe/0xa00
>
> [< ca06c196 >] ? SyS_exit+0x16/0x20
>
> [< ca00372a >] ? do_fast_syscall_32+0x9a/0x160
>
> [< ca5b6d62 >] ? sysenter_past_esp+0x47/0x75
>
> Kernel Offset 0x9000000 from 0xc1000000 (relocation range:0xc0000000-0xce7effff)
>
> --[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code 0x00000100

And after a few minutes:

> random: crng init done

The partitions were created manually with this format:

- sda1 - /boot - 200mb
- sda2 - / - 39.5gb
- sda3 - swap - 2gb

Just in case, I used the network installer for x86/i386 from [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#smallcd).

¿What can I do to fix/bypass this kernel panic error?

Comment: Once you are "dropped to a shell", check if the `/dev/sdaX` device nodes are present via the `ls /dev` command.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, i was working on something. Yes, the device nodes are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install a non-PAE kernel.

For some strange reason, the Debian 9 installer used the PAE kernel for recent PC's even if this is an old one that does not have PAE support (ironically, the non-PAE kernels say "for older PCs" in their description and in this case it was not used).

To start, I booted the installer in "Recovery Mode" with /dev/sda2 selected and /dev/sda1 mounted as /boot.

After reaching the command line, I updated the package cache (`sudo apt-get update`) and did an [apt-cache search](https://askubuntu.com/a/160899/763143) for the "linux-image" packages (aka the kernels):

> apt-cache search linux-image

The result was (reduced):

> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686 - Linux 4.9 for older PCs
>
> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-5-686
>
> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686-pae - Linux 4.9 for modern PCs
>
> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686-pae-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-5-686-pae
>
> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686-rt-pae - Linux 4.9 for modern PCs, PREEMPT_RT
>
> linux-image-4.9.0-6-686-rt-pae-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-5-686-rt-pae

So I installed `linux-image-4.9.0-6-686` to diagnose what was failing, the result was that the system booted and the login screen showed up.

After that I [removed the old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/a/153193/763143) and started using the system.

Answer (score 0):

That kernel panic is just a consequence of the system not being able to find the real root filesystem.

You cannot use `root=/` as a boot parameter, since at the point the boot parameter is used, the system has not yet mounted the real root filesystem, and needs this boot parameter to know where the real root filesystem is. Specifying `root=/` attempt to use the temporary initramfs root directory as the device containing the root filesystem, which is simply wrong and cannot work.

If your partition listing is correct, you should use `root=/dev/sda2` instead.

Comment: Using /dev/sda2 still throw the "ALERT! ... does not exist." even if the partition listing is correct (tested from a live CD)

Comment: Then the driver for either the disk controller or the filesystem type used on the root filesystem might not be included in the kernel or initramfs.